# image sticks out of the body [wordpress theme]

Tags: css, wordpress, image, width, document-body

Here is my site: http://highcatering.wpengine.com/

There is an image, almost at the bottom of the site, of a bride sitting on a couch. 
I applied the following statement on the stylesheet:

```
.novia img {min-width:1000px; float:none;}
```

I did that because I want the image to stay with a fixed height. It worked perfectly; however, that caused the image to stick out of the body (you can see it by reducing the browswers window width and scrolling right). I don't want that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the surrounding  container has a width of 100% you could hide its overflow-x.

```
figure.novia {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the novia class css

```
overflow: hidden;
```

It will keep the image the proper size (height) but hide any of the image that extends beyond the container ( in this case).